# How to verify whether the images are cached or not in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I want the images in my mvc 3 app to be cached. I've written a cache profile in web.config:

```
caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="ImageCache" duration="10" location="Server" noStore="true"/>
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

And added the OutputCacheAttribute to the method that returns images:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ImageCache")]
public FileContentResult GetImage(int productId) { /* implementation */ }
```

Qustions:

1) How to verify whether the images are cached or not?

2) What is the best Location for this: Client, Server, or Any? My app is a webstore, each image is attached to the product. I think every user should see the same cached content. Any suggestions?

3) Maybe this one is really silly: what is the difference between client and browser caching?

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) You could always check in your browser whether it fetches the image or not on subsequent request to the site. 
For example in chrome you can press F12 for the developer tools, then under the network tab look for your image. Http status 304(Not modified) will be the one you are looking for.

2.) Not realy sure about the pros and cons of different setting.

3.) Client caching means the resource is cached in your browser. Basically, your browser won't have to re-download the image. Server side means it is cachable by the server/proxy. For example if you have to query the database for the image, this isn't necessary anymore if the image is already in server cache. But the client will still have to always get it from the server.